# Coding & Designing dynamic WordPress menus

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to learn how to design WordPress themes, and I'm having a hard time understanding how, and what markup, WordPress generates for the main menu.

I inspected some different themes with Firebug, and it does not appear that they share the same markup for the Menu Items.

What I don't understand, is how one can style their menu, when they do not know what markup WordPress generates?

Also, I've been watching WordPress theme design seminars, and the guy creates a menu in the WordPress dashboard for a main menu, while some themes I have used, don't require that? Whats the difference?

I hope my question(s) are clear enough, if not please let me know. Thanks.

P.S: Yes, I have looked at the Codex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can create a list/menu of your WordPress pages. I think using `wp_list_pages()` will show them all. Calling `wp_nav_menu()` without passing in a first argument will also list all the pages. If you *do* pass in a "theme location" as the first argument only the menu assigned to that theme location will be displayed.

Check the WordPress codex for detailed information about each function.

Regarding the styling. As far as I know WP wraps each menu in a `div`, then all the menu items are put in `li`:s inside an `ul`. If you have hierarchies the nested `ul`:s will be put inside the parent `li`. WP also adds a BUNCH of handy (and unnecessary) classes to each li that helps you style the menu even further.

I normally just style the `ul` and `li` as they are *always* present in a WP menu.

Comment: Thanks! How would a newbie like myself know this? Isn't there any docs on this topic in the Codex?

Comment: If you know what function to look for the codex is great. If you don't I think tutorials are the way to go. I believe I found the `wp_nav_menu()` function when reading about custom menus somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track watching online videos and picking apart other themes, but it can be confusing!

Since WordPress version 3 there is a new way to create menus, like everything in web design there's many ways to do the same thing - each way can have it's benefits and drawbacks.

I found this article about WordPress menus by Justin Tadlock to be useful.

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just apply classes to the items you want to style in the menu module php if they dont have any already, then style them in the stylesheets ?